# When the ref callback argument is NULL in react?

Tags: reactjs

In some component when I use ref callback to receive component's ref, the argument of callback is null. When and in what situations the argument will be null?

Comment: Please provide some code snippet.

Comment: When it unmounts?

Comment: @hkg328 this is a conceptual issue. I think it doesn't need sample code.

Comment: @dpwrussell No. when you use a component in your component, it has been mounted.

Comment: > React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts. ref callbacks are invoked before componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate lifecycle hooks. From: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @dpwrussell It's true, but when a component has been rendered in another component and you see that in your browser, your component doesn't unmount yet.

Comment: can you create an example where the component is mounted but ref is null then?

Comment: @riwu As I said before, this is a conceptual issue and this isn't a case base problem.

Comment: Alright I guess the answer to your question "when will the ref to a currently mounted component be `null`?" is: **never**. The only way you can prove that that's not true is through an example?

Answer (score 5):

> React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the
> component mounts, **and call it with `null` when it unmounts**.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs